# How much initialization can/should be in C++ Initialization lists

Tags: c++, const-correctness, initialization-list

*This is my first post. I believe I am aware of best practices on stackoverflow but probably not 100%. I believe there is no specific post that addresses my interrogation; also I hope it's not too vague.*

I am trying to figure out good practices for writing C++ constructors
that do medium-to-heavy-duty work.

Pushing (all?) init work into initialization lists seems a good idea
for two reasons that cross my mind, namely:

- Resource Acquisition Is Initialization

  As far as I know, the simplest way of guaranteeing that members
  are initialized correctly at resource acquisition is to make sure that
  what's inside the parentheses of the initialization list is correct
  *when it is evaluated*.

  ```
  class A
  {
    public:
      A(const B & b, const C & c)
      : _c(c)
      {
          /* _c was allocated and defined at the same time */
          /* _b is allocated but its content is undefined */
          _b = b;
      }
    private:
      B _b;
      C _c;
  }
  ```
- `const` class members

  Using initialization lists is the only correct way of using
  `const` members which can hold actual content.

  ```
  class A
  {
    public:
      A(int m, int n, int p)
      : _m(m) /* correct, _m will be initialized to m */
      {
          _n = n; /* incorrect, _n is already initialized to an undefined value */
          *(const_cast<int*>(&_p)) = p; /* technically valid, but ugly and not particularly RAII-friendly */
      }
    private:
      const int _m, _n, _p;
  }
  ```

However some problems seem to affect over usage of initialization lists:

- Order

  > Member variables are always initialized in the order they are declared in the class definition, so write them in that order in the constructor initialization list. Writing them in a different order just makes the code confusing because it won't run in the order you see, and that can make it hard to see order-dependent bugs.
  >
  > http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-discussion

  This is important if you initialize a value using a value
  initialized previously in the list. For example:

  ```
  A(int in) : _n(in), _m(_n) {}
  ```

  If `_m` is defined before `_n`, its value at initialization is undefined.

  I am ready to apply this rule in my code, but when working
  with other people it causes code redundancy and forces reading
  two files at once.
  That is not acceptable and somewhat error-prone.

  Solution — initialize using only data from ctor arguments.

  Solution's problem — keeping work in the init list without
  inner dependency means repeating operations. For example:

  ```
  int in_to_n(int in)
  {
      /* ... */
      return n;
  }

  int modify(int n)
  {
      /* ... */
      return modified;
  }

  A::A(int in)
  : _n(in_to_n(in))
  , _n_modified(modify(in_to_n(in)))
  {}
  ```

  For tiny bits of repeated operations I believe compilers
  can reuse existing data but I don't think one should rely on that
  for significant work (and I don't even think it's done if calling
  noninlined separate code).
- How much work can you put in the list?

  In the previous example, I called functions to compute what the
  attributes are to be initialized to. These can be plain/lambda
  functions or static/nonstatic methods,
  of the current class or of another.
  (I don't suggest using nonstatic methods of the current class,
  it might even be undefined usage according to the standard, not sure.)

  I guess this is not in itself a big problem, but one needs to make
  special efforts in clarity to keep the intent of the code clear if
  writing big classes that do big work that way.

  Also, when trying to apply the solution to the previous problem,
  there is only so much independent work you can do when initializing
  your instance... This usually gets big if you have a long sequence
  of attributes to initialize with inner dependencies.
  It's starting to look like just the program, translated into an
  initialization list; I guess this is not what C++ is supposed to be
  transitioning into?
- Multiple inits

  One often computes two variables at once. Setting two variables
  at once in an init list means either:

  - using an ugly intermediate attribute

    ```
    struct InnerAData
    {
        B b;
        C c;
    };
    /* must be exported with the class definition (ugly) */

    class A
    {
      public:
        A(const D & input)
        : _inner(work(input))
        , _b(_inner.b)
        , _c(_inner.c) {}
      private:
        B _b;
        C _c;
        InnerAData _inner;
    }
    ```

    This is awful and forces extra useless copies.
  - or some ugly hack

    ```
     class A
    {
      public:
        A(const D & input) : _b(work(input)) {}
      private:
        B _b;
        C _c;
        B work(const D & input)
        {
            /* ... work ... */
            _c = ...;
        }
    }
    ```

    This is even more awful and doesn't even work with `const`
    or non-builtin type attributes.
- keeping stuff `const`

  Sometimes it can take most of the ctor to figure out the value
  to give to an attribute, so that making sure it is `const`,
  and therefore moving the work to the initialization list,
  can seem constrained. I won't give a full example, but think
  something like computing data from a default filename, then
  computing the full filename from that data, then checking if
  the corresponding file exists to set a const boolean, etc.

  I guess it's not a fundamental problem, but all that seems
  intuitively more legible in the body of the ctor, and moving
  it to the init list just to do a correct initialization of
  a const field seems overkill. Maybe I'm just imagining things.

---

So here's the hard part: asking a specific question!
**Have you faced similar problems, did you find a better solution,
if not what's the lesson to learn — or is there something I'm
missing here?**

I guess my problem is I'm pretty much trying to move all the work
to the init list when I could search for a compromise of what state
is initiated and leave some work for later. I just feel like init list
could play a bigger role in making modern C++ code than it does but
I haven't seen them pushed further than basic usage yet.

---

Additionally, I'm really not convinced as to *why* the values are
initialized in that order, and not in the order of the list.
I've been orally told it's because attributes are in order on the stack and
the compiler must guarantee that stack data is never above the SP.
I'm not sure how that's a final answer... pretty sure one could
implement safe arbitrarily reordered initialization lists,
correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: order - good compilers can warn you about this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath true if you can rely on compiler warnings that does help. I happen to be in a context where that's not the case, and I guess it pushes me to think having to respect declaration order is imperfect. But I agree with you.

Comment: The init-order matters: if you have a member that depends on other members, you need to put the member in proper order to get it right.

Comment: @Mine I'm aware of that, I'm just saying I don't see why it was designed that way, and I'm adding that I'm in a situation where it stops init lists from being usable as soon as there's inner dependencies.

Comment: Don't forget: as well as `const`, reference-members (`Class &c;`) need to be in initialisation lists too.

Comment: The reason that the constructor initialises the members in the order that they appear in the header file (rather than in the constructor) is that there is only one **de**structor, and that has to destruct the members in a known order. Which order? There is only one definitive, unchanging order, and that's the one in the class definition. If different constructors could initialise the members in arbitrary order, the destructor would have to find out what that order was to guarantee that it destructed them in the reverse order. Blecch!

Comment: @JohnBurger thanks for both your explanations !! Especially the one about order, that really stops any discussion I guess.

Comment: @JohnBurger "_If different constructors could initialise the members in arbitrary order, the destructor would have to find out what that order was to guarantee that it destructed them in the reverse order_" Only if you insist on destructing the objects in reverse order, an unnecessary requirement.

Comment: "`*(const_cast<int*>(&_p)) = p; /* technically valid,`" no it isn't!

Comment: @curiousguy _"Only if you insist... ...an unnecessary requirement."_ I do so insist. I need to know that the object I passed in at construction time is still going to be there at destruction time. If the compiler can rearrange the order of class variables behind my back, then I can't guarantee anything anymore!

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(const B & b, const C & c)
    : _c(c)
    {
        /* _c was allocated and defined at the same time */
        /* _b is allocated but its content is undefined */
        _b = b;
    }
  private:
    B _b;
    C _c;
}
```

the constructor calls `B::B()` and then `B::operator=` which may be a problem if any of these doesn't exist, is expensive or is not implemented correctly to the RAII and rule-of-three guidelines. The rule of thumb is to always prefer initializer list if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of my example, I was just trying to show the two alternatives. Thanks for the answer and sorry if I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

Since c++11, an alternative is to use delegating constructors:

```
struct InnerData;
InnerData (work(const D&);

class A
{
  public:
    A(const D & input) : A(work(input)) {}

  private:
    A(const InnerAData&);
  private:
    const B _b;
    const C _c;
};
```

And (that can be inlined, but then visible in header)

```
struct InnerAData
{
    B b;
    C c;
};

A::A(const InnerAData& inner) : _b(inner.b), _c(inner.c) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative

I don't see how that fundamentally changes anything for the user (the init list can be hidden in the .cpp regardless), and it still needs the InnerData definition to be exported with the class.

Comment: BTW, if `InnerData` is simply a copy of some internal of `A`, it would make sense to remove that copy and directly use `InnerData`.